# DateTime::createFromFormat doesn't work properly with format 2017-02

Tags: php

I have a following code, which would returns me previous and next date (selection by months). But I found it not working properly, when user selects a february. This is my code, which is applied to get the dates:

```
$dateSelect = @$_GET['datum'] ?: date('Y-m');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', $dateSelect);
$prevdate = clone $date;

$date->modify('first day of next month');
$this->view->next_month = $date->format('m');
$this->view->next_year = $date->format('Y');

$prevdate->modify('first day of previous month');
$this->view->prev_month = $prevdate->format('m');
$this->view->prev_year = $prevdate->format('Y');
```

I have made an example so you can test it faster: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be64147c4e962ea71328b9bd2bff12d66558f274)

If user selects date `2017-02` then it is processed as `2017-03`, which is incorrect. Try changing the value to `2017-01` in the example and you will see it is working properly. Since buttons in my code are filling with these values, my users can't go before `February 2017` without manually changing the URL.

Comment: The correct format should be with `|` (pipe char) : `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m|', $dateSelect);`. This will put the day and time to 0. See createFromFormat doc for other such chars available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DateTime will populate the missing `d` part of the date based on the ***current*** date, you're effectively getting `2017-02-29` (given that today is the `29th`), which isn't valid, but DateTime adjusts to a valid date by rolling forward into the following month, giving `2017-03-01`.

You need to force a `d` part to the date to avoid this default behaviour

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dateSelect . '-01');
```

Comment: Note : you could use the format with `|` (pipe char) : `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m|', $dateSelect);`

Comment: @Zimmi - it uses the default timezone setting for the server

Comment: Also has the benefit of setting the time to 00:00:00 rather than defaulting it to current time; that's a really great tip to pass on

Comment: @Zimmi thanks, it will be really handy in the future (since I already used Mark's solution).